# Zoom Out (scale) image to fit parent without showing background

Tags: css, image, css-animations

I need to scale or zoom out an image to fill its container, but, I need it to do so smoothly and without showing the yellow background. Is there a way to zoom out like this and not show the background? I am able to do this if I set the keyframes scale from 1 @ 0% to 1.05 @100% but it zooms the image out too much.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ope432pL/440/).

```
<div class="bg-contain">
  <div style="background-image:url(https://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a68/back-ground-background-sample-cluster.jpg);" class="bg"></div>
</div>

.bg-contain {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: yellow;
   position: relative;
   display: table;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-contain div {
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}

.bg-contain div:hover {
   animation: zoomout 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes zoomout {
   0% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: scale(0.93, 0.93);
   }
100% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1, 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: By background do you mean the yellow bit?

Comment: Yes the yellow bit.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, one is to make the background itself shrink, which I don't recommend, because it will  make the zooming image move strangely.

The other option is to simply make the background transparent like this.

```
.bg-contain{
...
background: rgba(255,255,0,0);
...
}
```

This uses the rgba (red, green, blue, alpha) color system. The first three numbers from 0-255 define the red, green and blue levels. The last defines the opacity from 0-1. The color I chose is yellow, but fully transparent.

[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ope432pL/441/)

Comment: I guess what I really want is for it to zoom without seeing the edges move towards the ends of the parent container, and I did not explain that very well. I may be doing it the entire wrong way. But this is what I originally asked and it does work.